Bucketing Values + showing actuall values
I have a interesting query which hopefully should test you abit!
I need to create a measure that does the following thing (This is my understanding of the issue, i could be wrong):
(Updated image in the example below)
IF the Ranking is 1 Dealer with the highest Volume - than show the value
IF  Dealer is "Barclays than show the value
Look at who is above "Barclays" in this example Raking 7 - show that dealer value
Look at who is below "Barclays" in this example Ranking 9 - show that dealer value
Else create a range of the volume i.e. 200-400,400-800, 800-1000, 1000-1250, 1250 -1500, 1500 +
I have created a measure but its not doing point 3 and 4.
Here is the measure used:
Volume Bucket Measure
VAR _selvol =
[Ranking Size (Vol)]
VAR _dealer =
SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Dealer Ranking'[Counter Party] )
VAR _range =
SWITCH (
TRUE (),
_selvol >= 0
&& _selvol < 200, "0-200",
_selvol >= 200
&& _selvol < 400, "200-400",
_selvol >= 400
&& _selvol < 800, "400-800",
_selvol >= 800
&& _selvol < 1000, "800-1000",
_selvol >= 1000
&& _selvol < 1250, "1000-1250",
_selvol >= 1250
&& _selvol < 1500, "1250-1500",
_selvol >= 1500, "1500+"
)
VAR _rankbarclays =
MAXX (
FILTER (
ALLSELECTED ( 'Dealer Ranking' ),
'Dealer Ranking'[Counter Party] = "Barclays"
),
[Dealer Ranking Number 2]
)
RETURN
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    [Dealer Ranking Number 2] = 1
        || _dealer = "Barclays", _selvol,
    [Dealer Ranking Number 2] = _rankbarclays - 1
        || [Dealer Ranking Number 2] = _rankbarclays + 1, [Dealer Ranking Number 2],
    _range
)

Ranking Measure
IF( [Ranking Size (Vol)] = blank(), BLANK(), RANKX(ALLSELECTED('Dealer Ranking'[Counter Party]),[Ranking Size (Vol)],,DESC))
Ranking Size (Vol)
VAR _currency = [DR Currency Count]
VAR _volumeall=
CALCULATE(
[Ranking Size],
FILTER(
'Dealer Ranking',
'Dealer Ranking'[Type] = "Vol. (MM)"))
VAR _volumeeur =   CALCULATE(
[Ranking Size (EUR)],
FILTER(
'Dealer Ranking',
'Dealer Ranking'[Type] = "Vol. (MM)"))
RETURN
SWITCH(
TRUE(),
HASONEFILTER('Dealer Ranking'[Currency]),
_volumeall,
_volumeeur
)
**Ranking Size **
SUM('Dealer Ranking'[Size])
**Ranking Size (EUR) **
SUM('Dealer Ranking'[Size (EUR)] )
Using Ranking bucket im getting this
I have created a sample report that can be accessed here:
My outcome is to identify where Barclays is being ranked and show the volume of 1 above barclays and 1 below Barclays
enter image description here
